# Why is my snapshot showing it contains data?

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a stream builder:

```
 StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance
              .collection('stripe_customers')
              .document(userId)
              .collection('sources')
              .document('source')
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return new Text("hello");
            }else {
              var userDocument = snapshot.data;
              return new Text(userDocument["card"]['exp_year'].toString());
            }
          },
        ),
```

When the `collection('sources')`doesn't exist I'm expecting `hello` to be displayed but instead the

```
{
              var userDocument = snapshot.data;
              return new Text(userDocument["card"]['exp_year'].toString());
            }
```

code gets executed. The collection doesn't exist on firestore...so I'm wondering why this is happening?

Answer (score 4):

You are probably getting an empty list `[]` but it isn't `null` so `hasData` is set to true.

You should check the length of the result:

```
if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data.length == 0) {
   // Nothing found here...
}
```

Comment: getting `DocumentSnapshot' has no instance getter 'length`

Comment: Try `!snapshot.data.exists`

Comment: same result. I'm not sure does the `exists` method is valid in flutter

Comment: `snapshots()` returns a `Stream<DocumentSnapshot>` so `snapshot.data` will be a `DocumentSnapshot` which has the `exists` getter. Specify the type in the constructor for better intellisense: `StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>`

Comment: thanks, with `exists`the code executes in the the braces(Text('hello')); Bu then then crashes with `The offending widget is: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>
I/flutter ( 4908): Build functions must never return null.`

Comment: Just make sure all possible code paths in your builder returns a widget, like the one in your question